# Reentrant locks and alien methods called from synchronized regions (Effective Java item)

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

From *Effective Java* (**Chapter 10 Concurrency**)

> Suppose 
>   you were to invoke an alien method from within a synchronized region while the
>   invariant protected by the synchronized region was temporarily invalid. Because
>   locks in the Java programming language are reentrant, such calls won’t deadlock

Now look at the following code :

```
// Broken - invokes alien method from synchronized block!
public class ObservableSet<E> extends ForwardingSet<E> {
  public ObservableSet(Set<E> set) {
    super(set);
  }

  private final List<SetObserver<E>> observers = new ArrayList<SetObserver<E>>();

  private void notifyElementAdded(E element) {
    synchronized (observers) {
      for (SetObserver<E> observer : observers)
        observer.alienMethod(this, element);
    }
  }
}
```

So consider `SetObservers` and `ObservableSet` are two independently written classes and they reside in different package and thus `alienMethod()` of `SetObserver`is alien to the `ObservableSet` class. Now say observers is not in a consistent state when `alienMethod` gets called. So where is the question of reentrant locks coming here ? The reentrancy will only come into question if the alien method also synchronizes on the same lock ie `observers' but this doesn't seem to be the case here or am I missing something here ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

And what happens if the `alienMethod` causes an event to get fired, which ends up re-entering that same `notifyElementAdded` method? This is a real-world hazard, I've been bitten by it once.

In this particular case you **must** make a safe copy of your list and run through it in peace.

Comment: but this is a special assumption you are making here. For your assumption , yes a copy should solve the problem but this is not mentioned in the quote explicitly. So lets assume we donot know what the alien method will do .

Comment: There is no special assumption in pointing out that the very same method may be re-entered by alien code. The exact number of hoops it will need to jump through is of secondary importance.